# $\dot{x}+ax = 1+\cos(bt)$ has a particular solution of the form $A+B\cos(bt-\phi)$. Find $A$ and $B$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, laplace-transform

Taking the fact that $x(0)=0$ I tried solving it using Laplace transformations and I reached that $A=\frac{1}{a}$ and you also have $\sin$ and $\cos$ on the solution I also tried to use the trigonometry identitie: $\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$ to get something similar and I reached that $B$ could be something like $\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}$ but it is wrong.

The answer for $A$ is good but $B$ any of my alternatives still wrong.

Comment: $\frac1{a^2+b^2}=B^2,$ not $B.$

Comment: !!! Yeah that's correct finally the answer got accepted. Thanks!. Can you please explain me what i was missing?

Comment: How did you reach that answer?

Comment: I tried with just pluggin into the ODE too but i had this $B(a\cos(bt-\phi)-b\sin(bt-\phi))$ and i didn't know how to approach it that's why i tried using laplace.

Comment: I identified termwise this $(Ba)\cos(bt-\phi)-(Bb)\sin(bt-\phi)$ with $\cos(bt)=(\cos\phi)\cos(bt-\phi)-(\sin\phi)\sin(bt-\phi).$